# Deserializing Claims from RSTR token using WIF

Tags: wif, saml, adfs2.0

I am building my own STS which handles different kinds protocols (WS-Federation, OAuth, etc...). I got stuck handling RSTR token which is posted by ADFS 2 to my STS.

The code I have successfully deserializes the claims, however I have to add part of the microsoft.identityModel configuration section in order for it to work and I need to add the ADFS 2 signing certificate in the Trusted People store.

I have my own configuration section where I specify things so using microsoft.identityModel is redundant.

Code:

```
    var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

    var message = SignInResponseMessage.CreateFromFormPost(request) as SignInResponseMessage;

    var rstr = new WSFederationSerializer().CreateResponse(message, new WSTrustSerializationContext());

    var serviceConfig = new ServiceConfiguration();

    IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = null;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(
                                new StringReader(rstr.RequestedSecurityToken.SecurityTokenXml.OuterXml)))
    {
        var token = serviceConfig.SecurityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(reader);
        claimsIdentity = serviceConfig.SecurityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken(token).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return claimsIdentity;
```

The necessary config that I would like to avoid:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris mode="Never">
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="27d3db77a9716ad370a7e9c632d5b98dcc5b1479" name="https://UrlToAdfs/adfs/ls/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would achieve this in code is by deriving your own IssuerNameRegistry implementation and applying it to your STS here:

SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry

On a side note, have you checked out the Azure Access Control Service (http://acs.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: That's the way to do it, although I still need to specify it in the config which is ok.

I have seen the Azure ACS and I must say it has some great features. The thing is we are researching how hard it is to create our own STS. Thanks for the help.